# Apache Camel message router

Tags: activemq-classic, apache-camel

We are developing an application which uses active mqueue and apache camel as router. This application is getting `.html` files as input (this files are NOT `xml` compliant). Depending on the prefix of the `filename` I have to route the file to different process. Actually the pattern "message router" `<choice> / <when>` does what I am looking for. The problem is the switch works over an `xpath` expression.

Then my question is: Is possible to access / apply the filename in a Xpath expression? If yes then how? if not then how can I cope this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: This is also posted on Camel mailing list, where its answered - http://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/Camel-message-router-tp5738769.html

Comment: Sure. I've posted first here. I got no answer then I've posted at that forum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/Camel-message-router-tp5738769.html Christian Posta has reported this solution which I've tested and it works.

```
<choice> 
    <when> 
        <simple>${header.CamelFileName} regex '^prefix.*$'</simple> 
        <continue...route...here/> 
    </when> 
</choice>
```